# TLS-PSK vs TLS-PKI

Tags: vpn, tls, pki, cryptography

I have read that once TLS-PSK encryption is about equally secure as TLS-PKI. The level of security by both depends on the data entered to configure the encryption. Could you please confirm this?

Here are the points I am interested in:

- What is the difference between TLS-PKI and TLS-PSK?
- Which encryption standard is more secure and why?
- If I wish to protect my access to the servers, will TLS-PSK suffice? TLS-PSK is significantly faster to configure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- PSK you give the key to someone first
- PKI you request the key after receiving something
- PSK is used more for things like access
- PKI is used more for things like authentication

past that your level of security is dependent on your encryption algorithm.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you for this explanation. In other words, if I configure secure connection just for me, I do not have to strive to have PKI. PSK should work just fine. After the communication is established, possible intruder will have the same difficulty penetrating the encryption.

Comment: Yes, just like if you and your home router want to talk, PSK is perfect, but distributing that key to 100s of employees is why PSK fails, key rotation is also a factor.